# How to set AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting to use all monitors & allow user to move the Full screen interface

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex, remote-desktop

I am using a [AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/msrdpclient9notsafeforscripting) to connect to a remote server. It works and works well, however, I'm struggling to figure out how I set it to use all monitors when entering full screen mode (same as the windows default Remote Desktop Connection below). I've looked at the documentation linked above but I don't see anything that accessible (or I don't understand how to access it)

[image].

Also, when in full screen, it seems the interface to the RDP is locked to the active screen when setting the full-screen flag. Again, like the windows default Remote Desktop Connection how do I allow a user to move the full-screen interface from one screen to another? And is there a way to have it enter full screen mode on the current screen rather than the primary?

Here's how I'm currently initializing

```
this._rdpClient = new AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting();

_rdpClient.Server = _ipAddress;
_rdpClient.UserName = _userName;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = _password;
_rdpClient.FullScreen = false;
_rdpClient.FullScreenTitle = this._fullScreenName;
_rdpClient.ConnectingText = "Connecting...";
_rdpClient.DisconnectedText = "Disconnected";
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.RedirectPrinters = true;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.PinConnectionBar = true;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.PerformanceFlags = 0x00000000;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.DoubleClickDetect = 1;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.EnableWindowsKey = 1;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.DisplayConnectionBar = false;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
_rdpClient.AdvancedSettings9.SmartSizing = true;
```

Does anyone have any tips to help me out here?